# Extending rowediting plugin to display more buttons in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, roweditor

```
// Custom RowEditor to have more buttons while rowediting
Ext.define('App.view.roweditor.TransactionRowEditor', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.RowEditor',

    initComponent: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    getFloatingButtons: function () {
        var me = this,
            cssPrefix = Ext.baseCSSPrefix,
            btnsCss = cssPrefix + 'grid-row-editor-buttons',
            plugin = me.editingPlugin,
            minWidth = Ext.panel.Panel.prototype.minButtonWidth,
            btns;

        if (!me.floatingButtons) {
            btns = me.floatingButtons = new Ext.Container({
                editor: me,
                renderTpl: [
                    '<div class="{baseCls}-ml"></div>',
                    '<div class="{baseCls}-mr"></div>',
                    '<div class="{baseCls}-bl"></div>',
                    '<div class="{baseCls}-br"></div>',
                    //I had to add the style width for the buttons to show up
                    '<div class="{baseCls}-bc" style="width:450px"></div>',
                    '{%this.renderContainer(out,values)%}'
                ],
                renderTo: me.body,
                baseCls: btnsCss,
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    align: 'middle'
                },
                defaults: {
                    flex: 1,
                    margins: '0 1 0 1'
                },
                items: [{ //**I added my buttons here**//
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: "Close",
                    handler: this.close,
                    scope: me,
                    tooltip: 'Close'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    handler: plugin.cancelEdit,
                    scope: plugin,
                    text: me.cancelBtnText,
                    minWidth: minWidth,
                    tooltip: 'Cancel changes'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: "MoreInfo",
                    handler: this.moreinfo,
                    scope: me,
                    tooltip: 'Click for more information'
                }, {
                    itemId: 'update',
                    xtype: 'button',
                    handler: plugin.completeEdit,
                    scope: plugin,
                    text: 'Save',
                    minWidth: minWidth,
                    disabled: me.updateButtonDisabled,
                    tooltip: 'Save Transaction'
                }]
            });
        }
        return me.floatingButtons;
    },
    close: function () {

    },
    moreinfo: function () {

    }
});
```

This is the rowediting plugin that I have used to add more buttons. But, the rendering of the buttons is happening at the beginning of my container and the row is not editable. could you suggest any changes that I can make for this to work at the row where I start editing?

**UPDATE:**

I have extended RowEditorButtons based on suggestion from @JanS

```
Ext.grid.RowEditorButtons.override({
    constructor: function (config) {
        var me = this,
            rowEditor = config.rowEditor,
            cssPrefix = Ext.baseCSSPrefix,
            plugin = rowEditor.editingPlugin;

        config = Ext.apply({
            baseCls: cssPrefix + 'grid-row-editor-buttons',
            defaults: {
                xtype: 'button',
                ui: rowEditor.buttonUI,
                scope: plugin,
                flex: 1,
                minWidth: Ext.panel.Panel.prototype.minButtonWidth
            },
            items: [{
                cls: 'mybutton',
                text: 'Cancel Transaction',
                iconCls: 'fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg',
                handler: function(editor, context, eOpts) {
                    console.log("stuff to do");
                }
            }, {
                cls: 'mycancel',
                iconCls: 'fa fa-times fa-lg',
                handler: plugin.cancelEdit,
                text: 'Cancel Changes'
            }, {
                cls: 'myupdate',
                iconCls: 'fa fa-save fa-lg',
                itemId: 'update',
                handler: plugin.completeEdit,
                text: 'Save Changes',
                disabled: rowEditor.updateButtonDisabled
            }]
        }, config);

        Ext.grid.RowEditorButtons.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);

        me.addClsWithUI(me.position);
    }
});
```

*I have read that it overrides for the whole project. What if I want only for the current page and for another page I want different set of buttons?*

Comment: I would suggest to override [RowEditorButtons](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/RowEditorButtons.html#Ext-grid-RowEditorButtons)

Comment: @JanS  could you please provide suggestion based on update?

Comment: either include the override only on the pages where you need it or surround your customization with a check if a specific parameter of the roweditor is true. and set this parameter on the roweditor where you need the buttons.